# Unable to read objects from firebase database snapshot

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to read latitude and longitude from Firebase and putting marker on those locations. But there seems some error crashing the app which I am unable to find even on Logcat. Tried putting some check Logs after each statement and found out that the problem occurs where I am trying to put values in class objects from the database snapshot. I am trying to use loop to fetch all objects from snapshot. Here is the structure of my database.
[image]

My Maps activity code where I am trying to put values from database snapshot to my class objects.

```
//reading stations from database
List<Stations> stations;
 mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("STATIONS");

    ValueEventListener stationListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            //found out that error is here
            for(DataSnapshot stationsSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                stations.add(stationsSnapshot.getValue(Station.class));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.i("Station Read[ERROR]",databaseError.getMessage());
        }
    };
    mDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(stationListener);
```

My [station class code](https://shrib.com/#st12st12) and [location class code](https://shrib.com/#loc12loc12).

Code to mark locations on the map fetched from firebase.

```
    //Placing all station data on Maps
    for(int i=0 ; i<stations.size() ; i++){
        LatLng location = new LatLng(stations.get(i).getLocation().getLatitude(),
                stations.get(i).getLocation().getLongitude());
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(location).title(stations.get(i).getName()));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(location));
    }
```

Comment: What is this third key under station1?

Comment: Try removing that extra field and run again.

Comment: @uneq95 I did, it didn't help.

Comment: https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-read-all-child-key-values-of-a-child-from-Firebase-database-in-Android/answer/Ritesh-Kumar-114?ch=10&share=bd24cc22&srid=icZQ This is what i did in the past. I am not able spot the issue with your code.

Comment: Initialise the stations array list before adding!

Comment: Don't move camera everytime you create a marker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initialize the stations List.

```
List<Stations> stations= new ArrayList<>();
```

The logic of adding the markers seems alright to me. Just adding it at the right place, as told by Momen, should work.

Comment: It worked but somehow I am not getting the markers shown on the map.

Comment: Is that related to firebase?

Comment: I dont know, but I think you can help me with this too. See the updated post.

Comment: Ok. Lets see it.

Comment: you have to execute the code that adds the markers at the end of onDataChange method "after adding the data to list"

Comment: @MomenZaqout it will execute right after fetching  the data.

Comment: @uneq95 it worked. All I did was shift the code where I am placing the markers inside onDataChange().

Answer (score 0):

1- The object `Stations` has to be like the object in firebase. like that

```
public class Stations{

public Location location;
public String name

//..getter and setter

public static class Location{
public double latitude;
public double  longitude;

//..getter and setter

}
}
```

the fields have to be public

2- initialize the arraylist

```
List<Stations> stations=new Arraylist();
```

Comment: The fields need not be public. They can be private if there are public getters and setters for them.

Comment: In firebase, with me, it has to be public regardless there are public getter and setter

Comment: Yeah, I just saw my code. I too have written public access specifiers. But I couldn't find anywhere in the docs if its compulsory to use public access specifiers.

Comment: if you have public getters and setters it works fine.

Comment: @uneq95 Yeah!, it's weird